# Bootstrap 4 - collapse sidebar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have my sidebar defined like this:

```
<div remove-class class="sidebar p-2 collapse width show" id="sidebar" style="flex-shrink:0;">
```

The directive "remove-class" looks like this:

```
a.directive('removeClass', function ($window) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
                if (getCurrentScreenWidth() < 768) {
                    $(elem).collapse('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I see that line `$(elem).collapse('hide');` is executed but it's not collapsing.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Why won't you use [angular.ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)? It's a native implementation of bootstrap for AngularJS

Comment: At this point it's not an option. The fact that I have a directive it's not that relevant (I think). The question is how to do it with Javascript in general.

Comment: Of course it's not relevant, it was only a suggestion and your question is perfectly valid. I'll post an answer if I can think of a solution